# How do I save my animation/manipulation in pdf?

Tags: export, animation, pdf-format

Is it possible to presserve my animation and manipulation plots in the pdf?

Comment: Do you mean [CDF (Computable Document Format)](http://www.wolfram.com/cdf/) or PDF (Portable Document Format)?

Comment: PDF is animation capable, but you will be in much less pain with conversions if you just use CDF - as @Silvia recommended.

Comment: @VitaliyKaurov I guess converting to animation in PDF would be highly difficult, if not impossible.. I personally like to see a convertor to Asymptote.

Comment: No I actually do mean pdf. As in files which are read by Acrobe.

Comment: Reason is because I need to include the animation in my LaTeX

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can export animations to [SWF](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/format/SWF.html):

```
movie = Animate[Plot[Sin[x + a], {x, 0, 10}], {a, 0, 5}];
Export["movie.swf", movie]
```

You can import them in LaTeX (see [TeX SE](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45242/animations-with-movie15-and-swf-files)):

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{media9}
\begin{document}
\includemedia[
  activate=pageopen,
  width=405pt,height=292pt,
]{}{movie.swf}
\end{document}
```

(I had to insert the dimensions manually.)

Comment: I often use `media9` to insert `mp4`s in my beamer presentations. However on OS X, it looks like only Adobe Reader can display them. Preview and Skim simply display a blank page

Comment: Preview (or native Mac pdf) does not support SWF/GIF/etc plugins.

Comment: I noticed that if I don't specify the  video dimension, nothing shows up. Why is that?

Comment: @jak Do you mean in the LaTeX file?  I know a lot about Plain TeX but little about LaTeX.  It looks like the default size is 0pt x 0pt. (Put rules around it -- they show up as a dot.)  You should ask on tex.stackexchange.com.  Perhaps there's a way to automatically read the image size.

Answer (score 4):

Actually,  *.avi or *. SWF can be read by Adobe Acrobat Pro.

You can try as  Michael E2 did:

```
movie = Animate[Plot[Sin[x + a], {x, 0, 10}], {a, 0, 5}];
Export["C:\\movie.avi", movie]
```

Use Adobe Acrobat Pro to open the file exported, i.e., C:\movie.avi.

Double click on the figure will animate it.

[image]