# How to place CDF file in Microsoft Word, Powerpoint or in interactive PDF file?

Tags: interoperability, cdf-format, interactive, slideshows, office

I would like to create a presentation for my lecture in which I would use *Mathematica* CDF files. Let's say I want to have such interactive content:

```
Manipulate[Plot[Sin[x (1 + a x)], {x, 0, 6}], {a, 0, 2}]
```

How can I place it in Word, Powerpoint or in Adobe PDF (I can use Adobe Acrobat) so it is usable? Usable - means not showed as an icon.

Comment: Strongly related: [Can we show some Dynamics/CDF in PowerPoint or Keynote?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12328009/590388) (the answer is: **YES!**)

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov I'm a bit surprised Wolfram Research doesn't mention this option. I haven't really played with Office, but had a hunch those tools would have relatively strong HTML embedding support. Can write up an answer demonstrating this?

Comment: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/24032/how-do-i-save-my-animation-manipulation-in-pdf

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can't. You can combine CDFs and content generated by other tools on web pages, though.

From [Frequently Asked Questions about the Computable Document Format (CDF)](http://www.wolfram.com/cdf/faq/) (Wolfram Research):

> **Do CDFs plug in to Microsoft Office documents or PDFs?**
>
> Currently, the CDF Player plugin only supports web browsers. We are exploring the same capabilities for a number of other applications. [Contact us](http://www.wolfram.com/cdf/contact-us/) for more details when CDF support for other applications becomes available.

Considering size of the Microsoft Office ecosystem, there is probably either a feature or an external tool that allows to export custom HTML (which is also used around CDF embedding on the Web) on spots defined in the Word document. This could enable creating CDF embedding in *exported* HTML, although something like only the link would be visible while editing the document in Word. This is probably a question for another forum...

Comment: Can notebook be placed in such file? Assuming I have a Mathematica installed on the same machine as the file I want to view?

Comment: @Misery Browsers support links to local files by [file URI scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme). Modern browsers also support embedding element data using [data URI scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme), but I have no idea how well CDF plugin works with that.

Answer (score 22):

You can install the [LiveWeb](http://skp.mvps.org/liveweb.htm) plugin for PowerPoint which allows to embed a live webpage into a slide. Now you should prepare an HTML page with emdedded CDF object ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7474579/590388) and [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/808/280) you can find old instructions how to do this, but probably there is easier way now) and embed it into a PowerPoint slide. People [say](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12328009/590388) that it works surprisingly well and you maintain full interactivity.

Here is how [this](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/12RhombicTriacontahedra/) Demonstration looks in PowerPoint 2003 after pressing F5:

[image: screenshot]

Full interactivity is maintained: you can scroll the page, interact with embedded CDF object and follow hyperlinks.

Comment: Even if this wouldn't strictly count as a solution, I'd hope it to be a workaround worthy of an accepted answer.