# Export and manipulate 3D plots

Tags: export, graphics3d, interactive, slideshows

How can I export 3D *Mathematica* plots such that I can put them into a presentation and still being able to rotate them?
Is there a specific format or does it depend on the program used to create the presentation?

Comment: I have been able to create an auto-rotating gif but I'd like to be able to manipulate the plot at will

Comment: Have you considered using a presentation notebook and doing the presentation with Mathematica?  If you don't have Mathematica on the computer that you'll be doing the presentation on then you can CDF the presentation and use the CDF Player.

Comment: Search the site for "VRML" and you'll get some hits

Comment: Concerning VRML, I remember that long time ago I used Mathematica in combination with Cortona to have movable graphics in PowerPoint.

Comment: I support Edmund's recommendation to use CDF.  Once you get a presentation up, the sizes sets, and so forth, the presentations can be amazing.

Comment: It could be good enough to make a movie of the rotation and then export that. If the presentation software can play movies you can get some interactivity by moving the slider manually. I do that quite often to avoid having to rely on plugins.

Comment: Strongly related: "[How to place cdf file in Microsoft Word, Powerpoint or in interactive PDF file?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/32566/280)"

Answer (score 4):

Here is an answer to this question derived from its comments.

- Currently there is no way to preserve the interactive capabilities of a 3D plot when using `Export`.
- If it is not possible to do the presentation with *Mathematica* itself, perhaps by using its slideshow capability, the next best recourse is to put the 3D plot in a CDF document and present it with CDF Player. Finally you can [embed the CDF document in a web page and display it within PowerPoint](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/32566/280) with full interactivity.