# Export a 3Dplot keeping the zoom, rotation properties

Tags: graphics3d

I want to export a 3Dplot but when I export the image remains quiet. I want to the image can rotate and make zoom and paste in to a Powerpoint, for the presentation I can explain to the public the graphics dynamically. I want to know how I can keep the zoom and rotation properties of all 3Dplots.

Comment: Simple idea would be to export as animated gif, many examples here. Can be embedded in virtually any presentation software. You loose interactivity, but presentation is about talking and bringing the idea to audience, not playing with controls.

Comment: Strongly related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/32566/280

Answer (score 2):

To retain a 3D description of your graphics, you need to export to a 3D format. Mathematica has [many built in exporters](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/3DGeometryAndModelingFormats.html) for 3D formats.

The bigger problem is how to get PowerPoint to display and interact with the 3D object - it has no built-in capabilities to do so. The usual advice is to embed a CDF into a web page and display the web page in your slide using a browser control or plugin. See [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/32553/862) for example.

Alternatively you could look for a plugin that will display 3D files directly (without CDF player). For example a google search for "X3D powerpoint plugin" returns some potentially useful results. I haven't tried this approach though. Do please post an answer here if you find something that works well.

The nice thing about using CDF player is that you can retain *all* the interactive elements of your output, not just zooming and rotation but also controls, animation and so on.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I'm a beginner and this is a challenge. I don't have time enough to finish the university's work, and I think that the most important is the public understand the graphics. I gonna save many perspectives of the same graphic to show us. Thanks for help. I'm gonna try to make a simply think.